# Google Sheets Import Range + Query combining first rows

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am using a query on import range to pull relevant data from one spreadsheet into another. It was working fine, then all of the sudden it started combining the first 8 rows into one row, but the rest are importing as normal. The columns are spaced correctly, but each column is concatenating the first 8 rows for some reason.

Here is my formula:

```
=query(importrange("other_sheet","Sheet1!$A$2:$O"),"Select Col1,Col7,Col2,Col3,Col4")
```

What can I do to make sure the first 8 rows each return into their own rows from the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to force it with `0` header rows like:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("other_sheet", "Sheet1!$A$2:$O"), "select Col1,Col7,Col2,Col3,Col4", 0)
```

Comment: That works! Why does that fix it? I am pretty new to the query function, so I want to understand how it works.

Comment: by not including 3rd query parameter, query will auto-assume on its own what to do and sometimes you get such a weird results